# Summation symbol operator with a parameter

Tags: math-operators

I need a summation symbol with a parameter, which should be an operator, so it allows, for example, to use `\limits`.

Up to now I have written one for each parameter:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumP}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{\mathit P}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumT}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{\mathit T}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumPT}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{\mathit{PT}}}
```

But I need many more parameters. Is it possible to write something like
`\newcommand\sumparameter[1]{\sum^{#1}}` in a way that it becomes a math operator?

Here is the full minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumP}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{\mathit P}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumT}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{\mathit T}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumPT}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{\mathit{PT}}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sumPTT}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{\mathit{PTT}}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \sumP_{i=1}^n X_i
\]
\[
  \sumT_{i=1}^n X_i
\]
\(\sumPTT\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like that? `\newcommand{\sumparameter}[1]{\mathop{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}^{#1}}}`

Comment: Yes. Thanks :-)
Can you reply it as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have correctly placed limits I'd use the `\sideset` macro from `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\sumparameterA}[1]{\sideset{}{^{#1}}\sum}
\newcommand{\sumparameterB}[1]{\sideset{}{^{\smash{#1}}}\sum}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\sumparameterA{P}_{i=1}^n X_i \quad\sumparameterA{T}_{i=1}^n X_i \quad\sumparameterA{PTT}_{i=1}^n X_i
\\
\sumparameterB{P}_{i=1}^n X_i \quad\sumparameterB{T}_{i=1}^n X_i \quad\sumparameterB{PTT}_{i=1}^n X_i
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The top version avoids clashes with long upper limits, though the lower one looks better with short ones IMO.